# Proof Check: Expected flips of getting HT on a biased coin

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, stopping-times

Finding the expected time it takes to get HT on  a biased coin where the probability of heads is $p=1/3$.

My attempt: For $x_i$, let $i$ be the state of the sequence, then using:

$$x_i = 1 + \sum_{j} p_{i,j} x_j$$

for $E(T_i)=x_i$, we get:

$$x_0 = 1 + \frac{2}{3}x_0 + \frac{1}{3}x_1$$
$$x_1 = 1 + \frac{2}{3}x_2 + \frac{1}{3}x_1$$

but $x_2=0$, so then:

$$x_1 = 1 + \frac{1}{3}x_1$$

$$x_1 = \frac{2}{3}$$
$$\therefore x_0 = 1 + \frac{2}{3}x_0 + \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\therefore x_0 = \frac{9}{2}$$

Comment: What do you mean by the state of the sequence?

Comment: I believe your work is fundamentally sound, but it is hard to follow.  What I think you are doing:  there are two active states.  State $0$, for which the last toss was *not* $H$ (this includes the start) and state $1$ for which it was.  We remark that $E_0=1+\frac 23E_0+\frac 13E_1$ and $E_1=1+\frac 13E_1$ from which your result follows at once.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I mean that $i$ is the state of the sequence and $x_i$ is the time it takes to get to state 2 given that we are in state $i$

Answer (score 0):

*Another Way*

By the geometric distribution, with $P(H) = \frac13,\;\;E[H] = 3$

From here, either we get to $[HT]$ with Pr = $\frac23$ or remain where we were

Thus # of steps to get from $H$ to $HT$,(Pr$=\frac23)$, again using the geometric distribution, $= \frac32$

So $E[HT] = 3 + \frac32 =\frac92$